# Query a Array in google cloud spanner

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

How can i query an array in google cloud spanner?

I have tried this

```
let query = {
    sql:`SELECT id, name, description FROM articles WHERE lang = '` + req.swagger.params.lang.value + `' AND tags ARRAY['` + req.swagger.params.tag.value + `']::varchar[]`
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to implicitly unnest your array element. As an example

```
SELECT id, name, description
FROM articles as a, a.tags as single_tag
WHERE lang = "your lang value"
      AND single_tag = "your tag value"
```

First, I implicitly unnested the array column `tags` to the column `single_tag`.

Second, I changed your `where` clause to an equality against the new `single_tag` column

Note: If multiple values in tags match your criteria, you can have the same row returned multiple times. You can address this by adding in a `DISTINCT` clause as long as none of the columns you are returning are arrays or structs. For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name, description
FROM articles as a, a.tags as single_tag
WHERE lang = "your lang value"
      AND single_tag = "your tag value"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i figured out in 5 mins ago ;-) - I think spanner is the missing link for the perfect stack at gcp! I LOVE IT!! Thank you for the great work!